# Median definition

Tags: statistics, means, moment-generating-functions, descriptive-statistics, median

Definition 6.1.1 (Median): We say that $c$ is a median of a random variable $X$ if
$\mathbb{P}(X≥m)≥ 1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}(X≤m)≥ 1/2$. (The simplest way this can happen is if the
CDF of $X$ hits $1=2$ exactly at $c$, but we know that some CDFs have jumps.)

Why the definition put the $<$ and $>$ with equal before $1/2$?
and what is the relation between the median and the sentence between the brackets

Comment: Be sure to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) next time.

Comment: Consider a continuous uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, so no jump in the CDF.  The median is clearly $m=\frac12$ but $\mathbb P(X\ge m)=\frac12$ and $\mathbb P(X\le m)=\frac12$ so you need to allow for equality